# 401.0000007 Error while trying to get the DHL Interface C# code. Followed DHL document

Tags: c#, dhl

I have been trying to connect to DHL interface but i cannot get the token access key from C# code. here is my current code. Please let me know if you have a solution -

```
 RestClient client = new RestClient();
            client.ClearHandlers();
            client.Timeout = -1;
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api-sandbox.dhlecs.com/auth/v4/accesstoken");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DHLClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DHLClientSecret"]);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Parameters.Clear();
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var local = response.Content.ToString();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return response.Content.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($@"Unable to authorize with GLS. Contact IT");
        }
```

here is the error i get -

> [https://api-sandbox.dhlecs.com/docs/errors/401.0000007"](https://api-sandbox.dhlecs.com/docs/errors/401.0000007%22)

**>> Solution :
this needs to be removed -**

```
    request.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: `HttpBasicAuthenticator` is for doing user password authentication

Comment: for getting access token i will need to pass the client ID and client secret provided to me. that can be used as user and password per the document on DHL. are you suggesting a different approach ?